# How to cast binary into a string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, casting, penetration-testing

For infosec projects I'm using strings as a kind of byte array.  This is commonly done in vulnerability testing.  In building the byte array, I want to concatenate printable characters and nonprintable characters.

This is not a question of conversion, I really want to cast the type.  I could write a function or method around chr(), but there must be a better way.

```
>>> print "A"*10 + chr(0x20) + "B"*10
AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBB
```

E.g., what if I have a large binary array to insert?

```
>>> print "A"*10 + 0xBEEF + "B"*10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

>>> print "A"*10 + 0xBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEF + "B"*10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects
```

I may be using the wrong data types here because I'm pretty sure that I'm not even guaranteed that strings have 8-bit bytes.

---

An example of what I would hope for:

```
>>> print "A"*10 + 0xBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEFBEEF + "B"*10
AAAAAAAAAA������������BBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: What's the output supposed to be?

Comment: In the last two examples, it wouldn't be human readable.

Comment: That doesn't matter... can you provide what that non-humanreadable output would be for your first example or even what A + 0xBEEF + B is supposed to be...? Is it a byte string you want, or a hex string or...

Comment: 0x20 is a space.  it's conicidentally human readable in this case.

Comment: So are you after a byte string? (and you might want to clarify you're using Python 2.x by adding the tag)

Comment: "byte string" sounds correct.

Comment: Unless you've got an `int` already that you want to convert to a byte string, any reason you can't just type it out, eg: `'A' + '\xBE\xEF\xBE\xEF' + 'B'`

Comment: Or maybe... `'A'*10 + binascii.unhexlify('BEEF' * 6) + 'B'*10`

Comment: that might just work... a bit of a n00b problem I know.    Can't chat, I'm taking care of babies at the moment :-)

Comment: Yeah... tapped on that by mistake when trying to tap on edit - ignore it :)

Comment: unhexlify looks a lot more correct, I'll have to read through its docs.  I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `binascii.unhexlify` if it's a bit of a chore to type out the escaped hexadecimals in a string, eg:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

b = 'A'*10 + unhexlify('BEEF' * 6) + 'B'*10
# 'AAAAAAAAAA\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xefBBBBBBBBBB'
```

In Python 3 though, you'd have to make sure you start with byte strings (or you'll receive a `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`):

```
b'A'*10 + unhexlify('BEEF' * 6) + b'B'*10
# b'AAAAAAAAAA\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xefBBBBBBBBBB'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the `struct` module, this gives you more control
on the output. Here is a Python 2.7 example:

```
import struct

s = struct.pack("6H", *[0xbeef]*6)
```

`s` is the following string:

```
'\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe\xef\xbe'
```

You can pack long integers, signed or unsigned, or double floats, etc.
For example here is the same hex values packed to doubles:

```
>>> struct.pack("6d", *[0xbeef]*6)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdd\xe7@'
```

There is also the possibility to specify endianess. And of course, to do the opposite operation (unpacking).